# Puppeeter change input vales

Tags: javascript

I have some HTML markup with radio inputs:

```
<div class="form-group p-o-popover-box">
    <div>
      <label
        ><input
          id="poi-5cf7ca81d0eb1"
          type="radio"
          name="po-5cf4fe14bd491_productRadio"
          data-price="0"
          value="Vacuum "       <--- Question here
          class="p-o-radio"
          title="Vacuum "
        />
        Vacuum
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label
        ><input
          id="poi-5cf7ca81d31d1"
          type="radio"
          name="po-5cf4fe14bd491_productRadio"
          data-price="0"
          value="Non Vacuum"    <--- and here
          class="p-o-radio"
          title="Non Vacuum"
        />
        Non Vacuum</label
      >
    </div>
  </div>
```

I want to trim and uppercase all input values on page before **scraping**, so i try this code:

```
await page.evaluate(() =>
  document
  .querySelectorAll(".p-o-radio")
  .forEach(v => v.value.trim().toUpperCase())
);
```

but nothing working.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

`querySelectorAll.forEach` does not work like `map` and it doesn't have a `map` function. You have to set it inside that `forEach`:

```js
await page.evaluate(() =>
  document
  .querySelectorAll(".p-o-radio")
  .forEach(v => v.value = v.value.trim().toUpperCase()) // Set v.value here instead of just returning
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getUpperCase() {
  let values = [];
  document.querySelectorAll(".p-o-radio").forEach((v) => {
    values.push(v.value.trim().toUpperCase());
  });
  return values;
}

const results = await page.evaluate(getUpperCase);
```

page.evaluate accepts a function as parameter. The function getUpperCase converts each of the value of radio button trimming and converting it to uppercase. The function eventually returns the set of values.Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, now it working:

```
const pureSelector = ".p-o-radio";

await page.evaluate(pureSelector => {
  return document
    .querySelectorAll(pureSelector)
    .forEach(opt => (opt.value = opt.value.trim().toUpperCase()));
},pureSelector);
```